# Why did my comment(s) get deleted?

Tags: discussion, comment, deletion

I recently gave [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3752701/224454) to a question.  Initially, I gave a sloppy answer—the kernel was there, but I didn't set it up properly.  Someone pointed this out, and after some time, I was able to improve the answer to my satisfaction (and, I believe, the commenter's).

After some more time, though, I came back to look at the question, and several of the comments were removed, including mine.  Now, I can understand the rationale behind the removal, since they largely (though not entirely) referred to parts of the answer no longer present.  There were some strident words, also—not from my perspective, but some could have taken them that way.

But they also removed some of the context behind comments that were left behind.  And usually, in my experience, the deletion of comments is left to the discretion of the commenters.  I don't believe my comments were harsh in any way; if anything, I believe they were conciliatory and admitted my error and my intention to correct it.  Can anyone give some insight as to why my comment was deleted?

Comment: Only mods can see deleted comments, so perhaps you should have flagged for mod attention, rather than post to meta.   mods far more often than not, delete no longer relevant, and problematic comments, only.  Perhaps there is a mistake here and there, but better to flag a mod than post to meta where no non-mod can read deleted comments to decide for themselves whether deletions were appropriate or not.  As I said, I trust mods 99% of the time in what they choose to delete.  But no non-mod can answer your question, so why post on meta?  **Hence the need to flag a mod for a question like this**.

Comment: @amWhy: I might have if I wanted the issue resolved.  I decided to post to meta because I wanted the issue explained. :-)  ETA: Also, I wasn't aware of that particular detail; thanks for letting me know about it.

Comment: when you flag, for moderator attention, the moderator handling it gives an explanation :-)

Comment: I understand the removal of inappropriate comments, but not the blanket deletion of entire threads which often include useful insights. It is vaguely dehumanising, as if personal interaction is not valued.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Now, I can understand the rationale behind the removal, since they largely (though not entirely) referred to parts of the answer no longer present."

That is mostly it. Comments are (very) often deleted when they are no longer relevant. Users can signalize this by flagging as "It's no longer needed." The situation is standard and very common: someone leaves a comment mentioning some issue/requests some clarification, the issues are addressed/clarifications are given, the comments are then deleted as no longer needed.

"But they also removed some of the context behind comments that were left behind."  - Just flag those as no longer needed too if you think that is the case.

If you want a reason as to why the procedure is like this, a quick summary is: this helps to avoid confusion due to conflicting information and reduce clutter in order for the unaddressed issues not to be overshadowed by issues that were already addressed or other extraneous things.

Comment: "Comments are (very) often deleted when they are no longer relevant."  I sense the logic behind this, and yet, sometime, they are still of interest to a sizable minority of the readership.  They may give some context to why something was removed from the post (even if, say, it was correct).  And they also provide some small amount of community. ¶ At any rate, in this particular case a series of comments that explained an error, and then my understanding of it, was unilaterally removed.  Strictly speaking those comments were not needed anymore, but it still seemed a tad heavyhanded.